# how to convert matlab to c# when the output is array?

Tags: c#, matlab

i try to take surf algorithm in matlab and to convert it in c#. 
The algorithm in matlab returns array of coordinates. The size of the array is [10,4].
In c# i wrote a code that doesnt returns the right information in the array. 
Am i missed something when i converted this code?

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\cbencham\source\repos\3.jpg"));
        Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\cbencham\source\repos\4.jpg"));

        //Get image dimensions
        int width = img1.Width;
        int height = img1.Height;
        //Declare the double array of grayscale values to be read from "bitmap"
        double[,] im1 = new double[width, height];
        //Loop to read the data from the Bitmap image into the double array
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = img1.GetPixel(i, j);
                double b = pixelColor.GetBrightness(); //the Brightness component
                                                       //Note that rows in C# correspond to columns in MWarray
                im1.SetValue(b, i, j);
            }
        }
        //Get image dimensions
        width = img2.Width;
        height = img2.Height;
        //Declare the double array of grayscale values to be read from "bitmap"
        double[,] im2 = new double[width, height];
        //Loop to read the data from the Bitmap image into the double array
        for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {
                Color pixelColor = img2.GetPixel(i, j);
                double b = pixelColor.GetBrightness(); //the Brightness component
                                                       //Note that rows in C# correspond to columns in MWarray
                im2.SetValue(b, i, j);
            }
        }

        MLApp.MLApp matlab = new MLApp.MLApp();
        matlab.Execute(@"cd C:\Users\cbencham\source\repos");
        object result = null;
        matlab.Feval("surf", 1, out result, im1, im2);

        // TODO: convert result to double Array [10,4]


        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What does the result contain?

Comment: the result contains array of zeros

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an object array to a double array. But for your purpose you don't need to. You just need to cast it to and object array and print its contents.

```
var arr = result as object[,];
```

or

```
if (result is object[,] arr)
{    
    for (i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i, j]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```